# Where is the leak?

Tags: objective-c, appleevents

I have a memory leak in this code. I am busting it since 2 weeks and I am starting to be mad.
Thanks in advance for your help :)

```
+(void) makeEvent:(int) event:(AppleEvent *)theEvent
{
    int sig = 'dock';
    OSErr err;
    AEAddressDesc targetDesc;

    targetDesc.descriptorType = typeNull;
    targetDesc.dataHandle = nil;

    err = AECreateDesc(
                   typeApplSignature,
                   &sig, sizeof(int),
                   &targetDesc
                   );
    if(err) { NSLog(@"Error creating descriptor: %i\n", err); }

    err = AECreateAppleEvent(
                         'DKoP', event,
                         &targetDesc,
                         kAutoGenerateReturnID, kAnyTransactionID,
                         theEvent
                         );
    if(err) { NSLog(@"Error creating event: %i\n", err); }

    AEDisposeDesc(&targetDesc);
    targetDesc.descriptorType = typeNull;
    targetDesc.dataHandle = nil;
}
```

`addIntParm` message:

```
+(void) addIntParm:(int) parm: (int) keyword: (AppleEvent *)theEvent
{
    OSErr err = AEPutParamPtr(
                              theEvent, keyword,
                              typeSInt32, &parm, sizeof(parm)
                              );
    if(err) { NSLog(@"Error setting parameter: %i\n", err); }
}
```

`addFloatParm` message:

```
+(void) addFloatParm:(float) parm: (int) keyword: (AppleEvent *)theEvent
{
    OSErr err = AEPutParamPtr(
                              theEvent, keyword,
                              typeIEEE32BitFloatingPoint, &parm, sizeof(parm)
                              );
    if(err) { NSLog(@"Error setting parameter: %i\n", err); }
}
```

`sendEvent` message:

```
+(void) sendEvent:(AppleEvent *)theEvent
{
    OSErr err = AESend(
                       theEvent, nil, kAENoReply, //kAEWaitReply
                       kAENormalPriority, kNoTimeOut,
                       nil, nil
                       );
    if(err) { NSLog(@"Error sending: %i\n", err); }
}
```

`Test` message:

```
+ (void) Test:(int)wid:(int)w:(int)h:(void*)points
{
    AppleEvent theEvent;
    [self makeEvent:'warp' :&theEvent];
    [self addIntParm:wid :'wnid' :&theEvent];
    [self addIntParm:w :'wwrp' :&theEvent];
    [self addIntParm:h :'hwrp' :&theEvent];
    [self addDataParm:points :sizeof(float)*4*h*w :'pots' :&theEvent];
    [self sendEvent:&theEvent];
    AEDisposeDesc(&theEvent);
}
```

Comment: Haven't spotted the leak yet, but got a question: why do you do so strange things with your methods names ? I mean, your methods are named `Test::::` and `addFloatParm:::`... why ? Also, what does Instruments say ?

Comment: Have you tried the [Leaks](http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/) tool?

Comment: I am new to cocoa programming. I will read cocoa naming conventions.

Comment: Uhm, what your code does is no different from a plain C code. Do you know you can define and use C functions in Objective-C source files? You don't have to use Objective-C method syntax.

Comment: No, I was not aware, How do you do this?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>My guess is that you're never destroying the `AppleEvent *` object.  The documentation for `AECreateAppleEvent` says:</strike>

> If the function returns successfully, your application should call the AEDisposeDesc function to dispose of the resulting Apple event after it has finished using it.

A clue to this is that the function has the word "Create" in it, which ([according to the Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029)) means you are responsible for disposing of the memory created.

(Guess I should read all the posted code before answering)

Since it appears you're properly disposing of stuff, I would run the Leaks instrument on your code and identify *what* is actually leaking.

Also, as @DarkDust points out, you should really read the [Cocoa Naming Conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Actually I dispose it (last line of Test function)